# Printing a hidden iFrame in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, printing, cross-browser

This solution works fine in Firefox 3.0+, but IE8/7 is just printing the entire page, not the specific iframe.

This is the function that gets called when the print link is clicked:

```
var printfunc= function(){
  var url = http://someurl.aspx;
  //This iFrame has style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9000px;"
  var printIFrame = GetObj('PrintIFrame');
  printIFrame.src = url;
}
```

The aspx that gets loaded into the hidden iframe calls the print function on the onload event handler:

```
<body onload="PrintJS.Print();">
```

The Print function:

```
 this.Print = function(){
      self.focus();
      self.print();
      return false;
 }
```

I've also tried this with "window" instead of "self". Both solutions work fine in FF but IE doesn't seem to get the scoping right.  Any thoughts?  A cross-browser solution would be great!  Also, I'd rather use CSS print styles, but the content that I'm printing is different than that on the page, hence the need to load html into a hidden iframe.

Comment: Is it to a secret printer that noone knows about? (sorry, couldn't resist :) )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solution: In IE, an iframe with visibility: hidden; causes the browser to print the parent.  Changing the styles to height:0px; width: 0px; fixes this issue.

Comment: What if we will use `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;`? In this case we don't need to set the height and width.

Comment: I have the same issue with `display:none;` however if I set the height and width to 0, and then toggle the display, do the `.focus()` followed by the `.print()` then toggle the display again, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Parent Document:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script> 
        function printIframe(iframe_id) { 

            if (navigator.appName.toUpperCase() == 'MICROSOFT INTERNET EXPLORER') { 
                document.frames[iframe_id].focus(); 
                document.frames[iframe_id].print(); 
            } else { 
                window.frames[iframe_id].focus(); 
                window.frames[iframe_id].print(); 
            } 
        } 
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:printIframe('printMe');">Print the iframe.</a> 
        <iframe id="printMe" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

iframe document:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>Print this.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

From the below link: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=449

Comment: Spoofing is not so 2013

Comment: Can you include the main ideas of the answer here? Link only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Try document.parentWindow.print(); instead of self.print()...