# Print iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, cross-browser

I have a button that loads a report for print into an "invisible" iframe inside a div and prints that iframe; the user presses a button to print the report (contained on a different page) without changing pages or any visual disruption aside from the print dialog. It works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE. In IE the parent page is printed in full, and a tiny messed up iframe is inserted at the bottom of the page (where I'm loading the iframe).

Here's the empty div without content, it's there so I have an ID tagged place to style and stick content with Javascript:

```
<div id="printerDiv"></div>
```

Here's the javascript function, onClick of my button this function fires and inserts my print page into an iframe inside printerDiv, after loading this page it prints:

```
function printPage(url) {
    var div = document.getElementById("printerDiv");
    div.innerHTML = '<iframe src="'+url+'" onload=this.contentWindow.print();>
        </iframe>';
 }
```

Here's the CSS hiding the div. I'm using absolute positioning to shift it off the visible screen area. I used to use display:none, but Firefox was unable to print iframes styled that way:

```
#printerDiv{
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
}
```

When I print in IE it prints the full page, and then at the bottom, where `#printerDiv` is, I get this little iframe:
[image]

So the content's being loaded, but it's not printing just the iframe, and it's not hiding the iframe properly either. Any other content I insert into `#printerDiv` is hidden properly, only the iframe displays like that.

I've tried all solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261561/printing-a-hidden-iframe-in-ie) in my Javascript function: using `self.prin`t, using `document.parentWindow.print`, changing the styles on the printerDiv to 0px height/width doesn't work either.

I'm welcome to solutions that don't use iframes (IE seems to have massive issues with them) but I need this ability to load content not visible on screen and print it directly via a button.

Comment: have you tried using [@media rules of css](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)?

Comment: @Einacio I am, and I used to use `display:none` in my screen CSS and `display:block` in my print CSS, it didn't work in Firefox. I don't know if it worked in IE either.

Comment: you could try selecting the frame from the `window.frames` array instead of using `this`, that maybe is referencing `window` in ie

Comment: @Einacio just did, Chrome and FF print the report frame only as they should, IE now prints the parent window and only the parent window, it didn't even show the iframe with the report.

Comment: what IE version are you testing against?

Comment: IE 8, needs to work in IE7 too unfortunately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

use something like jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to put the report inside the `#printerDiv` and differenciate it with CSS

on your CSS you have

```
#printerDiv{display:none;}
@media print{
    body *{display:none;}
    #printerDiv{display:block;height:100%;width:100%}
}
```

and the print button javascript

```
$('#printerDiv').empty().load(url, function(){
        window.print();
    }); //or whatever library/pure js you like
```

Comment: and i'm printing the whole page with everything else hidden. and not using iframes

Comment: you could load only in this page

Comment: you can add a class to the body in this js function before printing and remove after, and then in the `@media print` css `body.specialClass * {...`

Answer (score 9):

In my case, the solution was to *not* hide the iframe I wanted to print.  If I hide it (using display:none; visibility:hidden etc. ) the parent page would always print.

Instead of actually hiding the frame, I just made it 10x10 and borderless.  Now this works (with the delay trick).

Example code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function printFrame(frameId, targetContent)
    {
        var doc = $('#'+frameId).get(0).contentWindow.document;
        var $body = $('body',doc);

        $body.html($('#'+targetContent).html());

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#'+frameId).get(0).contentWindow.focus();
            $('#'+frameId).get(0).contentWindow.print();            
        }, 1000);        
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="contentToPrint">
I just want to print this stuff
</div>
<iframe src="about:blank" id="printframe" style="border:0" width="10" height="10"></iframe>
```

Button to print:

```
<a href="javascript:printFrame('printframe','contentToPrint')">Print frame</a>
```

Comment: This seems to work in IE10. For us, we dynamically inject the IFRAME so we also need a delay on the "disposal" (removal) of this frame to give time for the print dialog to pop up.

Also for the "visibility" issue, we absolutely position of IFRAME off screen.  {position: "absolute", top: 0, left: -2000, 'z-index': 20000, width: 1024, height: 500, backgroundColor: "white"}

This allows the content for format properly (as if it was rendered near-fullscreen, but makes it so IE10 will print it.

Answer (score 1):

```
`<script>

function framePrint(whichFrame) {

parent[whichFrame].focus();

parent[whichFrame].print();

}

</script>`
```

`<a href="javascript:framePrint('FRAMENAME');">Print</a>`

Change FRAMENAME to the name of the frame that you wish to print.

Comment: The iframe doesn't exist before the button click, but I tried this code (using the frames array) to `focus()` and `print()` the frame in IE. Again it works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE...

Answer (score 1):

I had a the same problem with IE11. It seemed like IE was ignoring the .focus() call and instead printing the parent page as well as the iframe. My solution was to inject a style tag that hid everything except the iframe right before printing then removing the style after the call to print. My code is here http://ironlasso.com/print-only-lightbox-or-modal-window-content/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue recently with IE10, added a timeout and got the result I wanted, the iFrame printed out instead of the parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selfPrint(){
    self.focus();
    self.print();
}
setTimeout('selfPrint()',2000);
</script>
```

Comment: the timeout doesn't even have to be that long.

Comment: This solved my problem too, but can someone explain why it works?