# Window closing before content goes to Printer (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, printing, callback

I have the following block of code which opens a new browser window with the current window contents, except in a stripped down layout for printing. It then sends the new page to the printer and finally closes the page. The issue i'm having is that the new window appears to be closing before the printer tab is getting all the data. Perhaps a call-back from the print() which then calls close() on completition? How would I go about implementing this functionality?
Thanks in advance.

PRINT LISTING

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function generate_url()
    {
        //var go_href = 'http:<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/admin/reservations/print_list';
        myWin = window.open('http:<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/admin/reservations/print_list');
        myWin.focus();
        myWin.print();
        myWin.close()
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there's any callback function for print. I suggest you can delay the window closing, which might help in some way:

```
myWin.focus();
myWin.print();
setTimeout(function(){
   myWin.close();
}, 6000);
```

Hope it helps in some way

Comment: Thanks for that Sudhir. That is what I have currently implemented but I'm worried that it will not work all of the time. If somebody is working on an old system or if the listing is very large, then it may take a long time for the window content to go to the print screen, and it could possibly close the window too early...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the JavaScript and new page entirely. Use a print media stylesheet to strip out (`display: none`) the content you don't want printed.

Comment: Thanks Quentin - could you elaborate some more on your explination

Comment: In case you don't know: Browsers have the ability to use a different CSS for printing, i.e. when you call `window.print()` or even print via menu, they apply different stylesheets: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/. So you have the "printer-friendly version" and the the screen-friedly version in the same HTML page. This may or may not be suitable in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Do not open a new window, but load the content to be printed in a hidden iframe

```
 var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
 ifr.style.display = 'none';
 ifr.src = '/admin/reservations/print_list';
 ifr.onload = function () {
      ifr.contentWindow.print();
 }
 document.body.appendChild(ifr);
```

You may reuse this iframe later for further printing, remove it after a ridiculously long timeout, or just leave it on the page.

Comment: Thanks Pumbaa80, that seems to be working perfectly and I'm happy to leave the iframe on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pumbaa80, but IE6/7 is eval!

so that i test in ie/7, it works!

in parent page:

```
var printIframe = document.getElementById('printIframe');
printIframe.src = 'print.php';

<iframe id="printIframe" style="width: 0; height: 0;" />
```

in print page:

```
<body onload="this.focus(); this.print();">
```

- [Printing a hidden iFrame in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261561/printing-a-hidden-iframe-in-ie)
- [Problems printing an iFrame](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-34283.html)